# Validation rules on picklist field and text field

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Need help in creating a validation rule,

As per the requirment,(see below)
I need a validation rule that does the following:

IF:
Production Type = Full Production, and Version = 1, or
Production Type = Full Production/Tax Update, or
Production Type = Full Production/Prelim, or

AND:
Value = [blank]

THEN:
Capture picklist options can only be:

Analyzing Files
Business Decision 
Capture Analyst Out

ELSE:
Capture Status picklist options can be the existing complete picklist.

The Data type of Production Type,Version and Capture is picklist fields and Value is text field.

According to the requirment i have created a below rule:

```
AND( 
   OR( 
      ISPICKVAL(Production_Type__c,"Full Production"), 
      ISPICKVAL(Version__c,"1"), 
      ISBLANK(Value__c)
   ), 
   TEXT(Capture__c)<>"Analyzing Files", 
   TEXT(Capture__c)<>"Business Decision" 
)
```

The problem with rule is that , Can't modify Production type,Version and Value fields until and unless i change Capture field to "Analyzing Files" and "Business Decision"
Could anyone help me on this rule.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
OR( ISPICKVAL(Production_Type__c,"Full Production"), ISPICKVAL(Version__c,"1"), ISBLANK(Value__c)
```

This implies that if any of the 3 is valid, the status needs to be one of the 2 statuses.

If you intend that the status should only be checked in case of all 3 fields having the particular value, replace the OR by and AND.

Then if you change any of the 3 fields to another value, the status will no longer be required to be on of the 2.